# Adding Currency Value in Css puts it onto seperate line

Tags: html, css

I've added the following to the css and html file:

```css
.currencyinput {
  border: 1px inset #eee;
}

.currencyinput input {
  border: 0;
}
```

```html
<td><span class="currencyinput">$<input type="text" name="amount"></span></td>
```

And my resulting page shows the $ and then the textbox on a new line below it. I was intending the $ to be in the textbox.

Appreciate any insight on this. Thanks!

Comment: Cannot recreate in Chrome. Is this browser specific?

Comment: I'm using Chrome and it's working for me...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider simulating an input field with a fixed using a span with a border around a border less input field. Here's a basic example:

```
<div class="container">
      <h3>Basic form example</h3>
         <div class="form-group">
            <div class="input-icon">
               <i>$</i>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="0.00">
          </div>
       </div>
 <div class="form-group">
    <div class="input-icon input-icon-right">
      <i>€</i>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="0.00">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
   <div class="input-icon">
      <i class="fa fa-bitcoin"></i>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="0.00">
  </div>
</div>
 <h3>Example using <code>form-inline</code></h3>
  <div class="alert alert-danger visible-xs">This window needs to be made 
          larger to see the inline example.</div>
   <form class="form-inline">
     Some text here
       <div class="form-group input-icon">
        <i>$</i>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="0.00">
   </div>
   <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
 </form>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
 .input-icon {
    position: relative;
  }

  .input-icon > i {
     position: absolute;
     display: block;
     transform: translate(0, -50%);
    top: 50%;
    pointer-events: none;
    width: 25px;
    text-align: center;
   font-style: normal;
   }

 .input-icon > input {
    padding-left: 25px;
    padding-right: 0;
  }

 .input-icon-right > i {
     right: 0;
  }

 .input-icon-right > input {
     padding-left: 0;
     padding-right: 25px;
     text-align: right;
   }
```

Comment: yes this looks great for putting a currency amount outside the input box which I may have to go with. I was intending the currency to show up within the input box though. Thank you for your response!

Answer (score 0):

> use this css for remove focus border    `input:focus{outline: none;}`

```css
.currencyinput span{
   position: relative;
}
.currencyinput input{
   padding-left:20px; 
}
.currencyinput span{
 left:15px;
 top:0
  position: absolute;
}
.currencyinput input:focus {
   outline: none;
}
```

```html
<span class="currencyinput"><span>$</span><input type="text" name="amount"></span>
```

Comment: I tried your suggestions and it made some changes to the spacing but its still on separate lines.

Comment: I've added your additional code and it still did not change. I'm wondering if perhaps the other CSS code in my file may be conflicting with this? I will have to take a further look.